# Get List<T> values with late binding

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a `List<T>` variable where T is not known at compile time. I need to access the `value` property on type `T` like this

```
foreach(var item in items) // items is List<T>
{
    item.value // this won't compile because T is unknown 
}
```

I know that `<T>` in my case will have the `value` property. How can I access it?

Comment: Does each "T" always have the same property name? If so consider an base class/interface that each inherits from. You can then constraint T to the base type/inferface

Comment: no each time "T" can have other properties

Comment: Are you planning to choose a specific property for each possible input type?

Answer (score 10):

If you **KNOW** that every T has *VALUE* you can use `dynamic` instead of `var`

```
foreach(dynamic item in items) //items is List<T>
{
    item.VALUE
}
```

Comment: The intellisense won't tell you that `item.value` exists. However, it will compile and work on runtime (if `item.value` doesn't exists then you'll get a runtime exception

Comment: Although this might work, I'm not generally a fan of 'throwing dynamic' at a problem to make it go away. The underlying problem is in the design, which should be solved using interfaces.

Comment: @Baldrick, indeed so. I'm not a fan of dynamic myself but it is a valid solution if you can't work / change the design and you want to avoid huge boilerplate

Answer (score 3):

As already answered the correct way is to create an interface that implements the Value prop.

However you have commented that you have no control over classes you will need to do this another way.

One way would be reflection, I'm assuming your property name is VALUE, (case sensitive)

```
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty("VALUE");
object value = pi == null ? null pi.GetValue(item,null);
```

You could cache the reflection call into a static generic class that creates a static field the first time it is used.

Alternatively you could use a static generic helper class with field and a helper method.

```
 public static class ValueHelper<T> {
     public static Func<T,object> ValueFunction;

     public static object GetValue(T item) {
        var function = ValueFunction;
        return function == null ? null : function(item);
     }

     }
 }
```

Then somewhere in your code, where you know T, eg you want to setup for MyClass

```
  ValueHelper<MyClass>.ValueFunction = x => x.Value;
```

Then your list code becomes

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    value = ValueHelper<T>.GetValue(item);
}
```

Comment: The last loop won't compile. You can't have type on the right of `in` it has to be an expression.

Comment: zespri you are right, I don't know why I did that, now corrected

Comment: You and others simply copy-pasted the mistake that was in the original question. Happens to everyone =)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a control over T classes, you can introduce an interface with Value property and make every T class implement this interface. In that case you can enumerate list values like this:

```
    foreach(IMyInterface item in items)
    {
        var someVar = item.VALUE; 
//you know that item does have VALUE property and the type of that property as declared in interface
    }
```

UPD. It works even if your T classes have different properties:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    string VALUE{get;set;}
}

class A : IMyInterface
{
   public int Aprop{get;set;}
   public string VALUE{get;set;}
}

class B : IMyInterface
{
   public int Bprop{get;set;}
   public string VALUE{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: No I don't have control on T classes

Comment: well, than use dynamic if you absolutely sure T class has VALUE property. To do something meaningful with VALUE just cast it to whatever class you expect.

Comment: VALUE is only example

Answer (score 0):

If T types are known in advance then you can do this (not the best approach but those are already explained in other answers):

```
foreach(var item in List<T>)
{
  if (item.GetType().Equals(typeof(fooClassA)))
  {
     ret = (item as fooClassA).VALUE_A;
  }
  if (item.GetType().Equals(typeof(fooClassB)))
  {
     ret = (item as fooClassB).VALUE_B;
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: That type checking is kinda ugly.  Is there a good reason not to use, say, `if (item is fooClassA)`?  (You don't really have to worry about subclasses breaking things, unless you're in the habit of violating LSP.)

Comment: @cHao didn't know that syntax. That's definitely more elegant!